# Как просмотреть список причин закрытия

Tags: поддержка, предложение, причины-закрытия

Знаю, что [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465650/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-c) закрывался минимум с 4 различными причинами, но показывается только одна. Во-первых, как просмотреть остальные? Во-вторых, вроде где-то (возможно, на enSO) встречал вопросы, где в списке отображалось две причины - почему тут только одна?

Comment: Я у нас тоже видел две причины в каком-то вопросе.

Comment: @LEQADA, я нашёл. Гугл всё помнит :)

Comment: @Discord, и всё-таки я предлагаю эти списки где-то отображать.

Comment: @Qwertiy С этим предложением надо идти на MSE, здесь об этом писать бесполезно.

Comment: @Discord, у меня там рейтинга даже на просмотр удалённых сообщений не хватает - вероятно, они сильно удивятся, увидев от меня такой вопрос :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Удалённые вопросы-то тут при чём? Тут голосование за закрытие и отображение результатов. Что вопрос про совместительству удалён — это иррелевантно. И никто не удивится, на том сайте у подавляющего большинства юзеров СЕ очень мало репы.

Comment: @Discord, большинство таких вопросов удаляют со временем... Я даже примеры вряд ли найду.

Comment: @Qwertiy Начните с поиска уже существующего запроса на данную тему. Он наверняка уже есть. Не тратьте время впустую.

Answer (score 2):

У каждого сообщения на сайте есть «временная шкала» всех событий привязанных к нему. Доступ к этой шкале имеют выбранные сообществом модераторы и сотрудники компании. На сколько мне известно, у остальных участников возможности посмотреть историю голосов за закрытие (и причины) *после закрытия вопроса* нет.

См. также: [привилегия «просмотр голосов за закрытие»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

Comment: "историю тревог" - это опечатка или за этим что-то кроется?

Comment: @Qwertiy Опечатка. Спасибо за замечание, поправил.

Comment: А в каких случаях выводится несколько причин закрытия одновременно?

Comment: @Qwertiy На сколько знаю, такого не бывает.

Comment: Я точно где-то видел.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460711/ошибка-в-работе-плагина-jszip

Comment: Подозреваю, что при равенстве числа голосов за них? Если бы пятая тоже была другой, то вывалились бы все 5 причин?))))

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465852/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 - тут вообще не указана причина.

Comment: А я долго искал и не нашёл. Понятно теперь.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky когда 2 и 3 голоса за две причины соответственно, то показываются обе под вопросом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в гугл с кавычками: `"Те, кто, голосовал за его закрытие, указывали следующие причины"`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а в каком случае ни одной не указывается?

Comment: @Qwertiy: я там вижу, что указана причина "не по теме".

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а если посмотреть внимательнее, то везде стоит тире и список пользователей, голосовавших за эту причину. А в этом вопросе никого. Это раз. А два - это то, что отображёт общий комментарий для группы "не по теме" - так проголосовать нельзя в принципе - надо выбрать одну из подпричин.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Хм, действительно. Возможно, общая причина выбирается, когда пользователи голосовали за разное и нет лидирующей причины.

Answer (score 1):

Список причин закрытия вопроса — это производство Glucalo Company. Насколько я понимаю, несколько причин показываются при выполнении следующих условий:

1. Как минимум, 3 и 5 голосов за закрытие находились в категории "Оффтопик".
2. Как минимум, 2 разные причины выбраны из категории "Оффтопик".

В этом случае выводится список причин для закрытия *только из категории "Оффтопик"*, а рядом с ними отображаются проголосовавшие за соответствующие причины. При этом остальные причины и, соответственно, списки голосовавших за них не отображаются (есть только общий список голосовавших за закрытие).

Возможно, разные причины отображаются, и если нет "победителя", но такие случаи — статистическая погрешность.

Почему так странно реализовано? Видимо, считается, что причины для закрытия из категории "Оффтопик" наиболее содержательны, а слишком длинный список причин испугает пользователей.

Думаю, на MSE можно найти предложение с исправлением текущего поведения. Либо проигнорированное, либо закрытое, как повелось.

Comment: "При этом голосовавшие за причины закрытия из других категорий нигде не отображаются, равно как и собственно остальные причины." - это немного не так. Список проголосовавших как раз отображается - все пятеро, а вот причин, которые они указали нет. [Пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465852)

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, неправильно выразился, исправил.